# How to understand the dynamic binding in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding

This is my code. I need help making this Dynamic Binding work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class Shape {
    protected:
    double x,y;
    public:
    void get_data(double a,double b=3.14)   {
        x=a;
        y=b;
    }   
    virtual void display_area(){
    };
};

class Rectangle : public Shape  {
    public:
    void display_area() {
        cout<<"\nArea of Rectangle : "<<x*y<<" units.\n";
    }
};
class Circle : public Shape {
    public:
    void display_area() {
        cout<<"\nArea of Circle : "<<y*x*x<<" units.\n";
    }
};
class Triangle : public Shape   {
    public:
    void display_area() {
        cout<<"\nArea of Triangle : "<<0.5*x*y<<" units.\n";
    }
};

main()  {
    Shape *ptr;
    char opt,wait;
    double a,b;
    do{
        system("cls");
        cout<<"\n1.Area of Rectangle\n2.Area of Circle\n3.Area of Triangle\n4.Exit\n\nEnter your Option : ";
        opt=getche();
        switch(opt) {
            case '1':
                *ptr = new Rectangle;
                cout<<"\nEnter Length : ";
                cin>>a;
                cout<<"\nEnter Width  : ";
                cin>>b;
                ptr->get_data(a,b);
                ptr->display_area();
                break;
            case '2':
                *ptr = new Circle;
                cout<<"\nEnter Radius : ";
                cin>>a;
                ptr->get_data(a);
                ptr->display_area();
                break;
            case '3':
                *ptr = new Triangle;
                cout<<"\nEnter Base   : ";
                cin>>a;
                cout<<"\nEnter Height : ";
                cin>>b;
                ptr->get_data(a,b);
                ptr->display_area();
                break;
            case '4':
                cout<<"\n\nGoodBye ! Have a Nice Day !\n";
                exit(0);
            default:
                cout<<"\n\nEnter a Valid Option !\n";
        }
        cout<<"\n\nPress Any Key to Continue....";
        wait=getche();
    }while(opt!='4');
}
```

The error I get is:

```
5   7  [Note] Shape& Shape::operator=(const Shape&)

5   7  [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Rectangle*' to 'const Shape&'

55  10 [Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Shape' and 'Circle*')

55  10 [Note] candidate is:

5   7  [Note] Shape& Shape::operator=(const Shape&)

5   7  [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Circle*' to 'const Shape&'

62  10 [Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Shape' and 'Triangle*')

62  10 [Note] candidate is:

5   7  [Note] Shape& Shape::operator=(const Shape&)

5   7  [Note] no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Triangle*' to 'const Shape&'
```

Comment: **Please take a few weeks to read a [good C++ programming](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book** then [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and more about [virtual method tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `ptr` incorrectly. You should not be dereferencing it when assigning an object to it.

Change this

`*ptr = ...;`

To this

`ptr = ...;`

Also, you are leaking the objects you allocate with `new`. You need to call `delete ptr;` when you are done using each object. Which also means you need to add a virtual destructor to `Shape` so the proper descendant destructor is called correctly:

```
class Shape {
... 
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {}
...
};
```

Comment: That was truly helpful. It resolved my problem. Please tell me more about 'dereferencing'.. im confused.

Comment: @Cyber-x-x-Stunner you should read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/). There are whole chapters on what pointers are and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to supplement. Don't use raw pointer.
If you used smart ponter [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) then you could avoid mistakes. And you don't need to think about deleting object.
For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Shape> ptr;
ptr = std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
```